# Console-based markdown reader

Tags: software-recommendation, console

I am working on a remote server that only has a terminal support. There are certain markdown files that I would like to read. However, as I don't have a GUI support, I am in need of a markdown reader/ something similar. The server has lynx installed. So, even if you can suggest some extension to lynx, it will work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can think of converting it to html with some tool like pandoc, then read the html with lynx. For eg, with pandoc:

```
pandoc file.md | lynx -stdin
```

Answer (score 6):

This is old but for future googlers: I had the same problem and ended up adding this to `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
function mdread {
    pandoc "$1" -f markdown -t html | lynx -stdin
}
```

Then simply do `mdread foo.md`, and it will open in lynx. This is possibly not optimal but a lot better than just looking at the source. You'll need pandoc and lynx of course.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a lightweight terminal markdown viewer in python, for CLI or as lib:

https://github.com/axiros/terminal_markdown_viewer

It supports e.g. tables, admonitions and tons of color themes.

Answer (score 2):

Markdown is already in the most readable form for a console by design. Lynx displays HTML lists as bullet points using asterisks -- exactly the same way as you write Markdown manually.

tl;dr: What you need is known as a "text editor". Nothing more.

Comment: Consoles can display text in bold, and with inverted foreground/background, and most consoles can even display in color. This could provides for something more readable than displaying asterisks and underscores surrounding bold and italicized text, and *hugely* more readable than displaying backticks surrounding inline code-formatted text. While markdown is reasonably easy to read, it's decidedly not "the most readable form" to read documents in a terminal.

Comment: Why not try a text editor with syntax highlighting? Vim is great for this. Just `:set ft=markdown` if it doesn't automatically recognize it.